# How to set paper size to unlimited in delphi 7

Tags: delphi, printing, delphi-7, quickreports

I'm developing a cashier application using Delphi 7 and QuickReport 3.0.9.

The problem is the printing module is limited to the size of the component length in the form, so when the user prints a very long list of item, some of the items will get cut off. The printer is a special printer for cashiers (I don't know the correct name for this printer) that uses a roll of paper, so the printout length should be unlimited.

How do I set the printout length to unlimited? I already emptied the QuickRep1 - Page - Length property but it's still cut off at some point.

Comment: It's called a "Receipt Printer" - a printer which prints receipts.

Comment: @JerryDodge thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot do it with QuickReport v3.0.9.

Support for continuous paper has been introduced with [QuickReport v5 update](http://www.quickreport.co.uk/webinfopage.aspx?WebInfoID=158):

> **Continuous paper**. A new property of `TPage`, `Continuous` adds support for printing from rolls

When you set the `Continuous` property to `true`, the report should not contain any newpage commands.